# Difference between min and fmin

Tags: swift, uikit

I have two `CGFloats`. Is there any difference between

```swift
let a: CGFloat = ...
let b: CGFloat = ...

min(a, b)
```

and

```swift
fmin(a, b)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

`fmin` is `CoreGraphics` `C` function to find minimal value between 2 `CGFloats`

```swift
public func fmin(_ lhs: CGFloat, _ rhs: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
```

`min` is Swift function that takes 2 `Comparable` and return smallest from them

```swift
public func min<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T where T : Comparable
```

In general here will be no difference between using first or second. But I would recommend using `min` because Swift probably could better optimize its calls.